# Why is min-height stretching the div's to the full length of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I want the length of the .thumbnail div's to be as long as the longest in the row. So for that I add min-height: 100%; to the .thumbnail css styles. The result is that they become as long as the whole page. Somehow I don't see what is wrong with it and it is killing me for 1,5 days now. I stripped my code down to actual problem. I got it working on my site www.koenpack.com but even when I compare the code, I don't see why it is not working. Your help will be appreciated!

```
<html lang="nl-nl">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row flex-container">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 flex-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h1>Luxe papieren draagtassen</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 flex-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h1>Budget draagtassen</h1>
                    Some more <br /> Content
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 flex-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h1>Basic papieren draagtassen</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 flex-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h1>Geschenkverpakkingen</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 flex-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h1>Nonwoven draagtassen</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 flex-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h1>Verzendverpakkingen</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .flex-container h1 {
            font-size: 10px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .flex-container {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            display: flex;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .flex-item {
            padding-bottom: 14px;
            padding-left: 7px;
            padding-right: 7px;
            float: none;
            position: relative;
        }

        .thumbnail {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
            max-width: 100%;
            padding: 4px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(194, 194, 194);
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code into snippet.

Comment: Well, the thing is, when I run the code in jsfiddle.net, it works fine...
https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/142783/

Comment: @Ron Splinter  Is your problem solved?

Comment: No, when I run it in fiddle, it runs fine, but when I run it in a browser, it doesn't...

Comment: Can you update your question with browser screenshot.!

Comment: When I test the html in firefox, it works well, but not in IE and Chrome

Comment: What browser do you use? I looked at your website using Opera and I can't see the problem you're describing

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: CSS percent heights are relative to the first parent with a defined height or width value (that is, not `auto`). Since you haven't defined any static sizes, the 100% means "100% of the whole page", because the first element with a defined height is the body element.

Comment: @Kilves I understand what you are saying and indeed when I set the height of .flex-item to 300px, all .thumbnails adjust to that 300px. But I want them to be dynamically as high as the highest div in that row. It works on koenpack.com so it should be possible.

Comment: Unbelievable how such a small issue can take 2 days of your time. Never in 10 years of development has my frustration level been this high.

Comment: Solved! <!DOCTYPE html> was missing at the top of the page.